# Is there a BASE64 Encoding Function using SQL in Automation Studio?

Tags: marketing-cloud, dataextensions, sql, automationstudio, base64

We'd like to `BASE64 Encode` our Email Addresses so we can send them to an external third-party (it's the third-party's requirement).  We know how to do it using `AMPscript`, but not in SQL.

Ultimately, we would like to create a query that pulls all the email addresses and places them into a new Data Extension as `BASE64 Encoded` values.

Is this possible?

Comment: How many records do you have to encode, and how often will this process need to be run? Is it a single batch of many thousands, or do you need a daily encode of a few hundred?

Comment: For now, it's a one-time encoding so we can export values to a third-party.  There is close to 1mm rows

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can have 2 steps in your automation to solve this:

[image]

1- SQL Query to Pull data into a DE

2- SSJS Script to go through the Data extension and Update an "encodedEmail" field with the new encoded email using the Base64encode() Method. (Documentation Link below)

https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.noversion.mc-programmatic-content.meta/mc-programmatic-content/ssjs_utilitiesBase64Encode.htm

To improve performance you can add an "If" statement to only update empty "encodedEmail".